# Verify Linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra

Verify linear independence of the following sets of vectors: $\{1−x, x+x^2, 1+ x^2 \} $ in $\Bbb R[x]$ over $\Bbb R$

How  to solve this?

We are checking $a(1-x)+b(x+x^2)+c(1+x^2)=0$, but it gives $x^2=-1$.

I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a(1-x)+b(x+x^2)+c(1+x^2)=0 \to (b+c)x^2+(b-a)x+(a+c)=0$$

We have then a polynomial identity, because the above equation has to be true for every $x \in \Bbb R$, then:

$$b+c=0\\
b-a=0\\
a+c=0$$

what give us $a=b$ and $c=-b$.

That give us infinite non null solutions (just take $b\ne 0$) and then they are linearly dependent.